# JQuery addClass and removeClass efficiency

Tags: jquery, optimization, addclass, removeclass

I am building a sortable table and need the update the 'sort order' icons on the table header.

Here is a little information so you can better understand what my code is doing.

The code is being executed from within a click event, and `$(this)` references the table header cell being clicked.

The table header cell has three spans in it; a wrapper, a text span, and a icon span. Here is how it looks

```
<span class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-icon-secondary'>
  <span class='ui-button-text'>text</span>
  <span class='ui-button-icon-secondary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s'></span>
</span>
```

`collection` is a return from `$("thead:first th")`

and here is my code that does the switch on the icons.

```
var new_class = sort_info.order == "asc" ? "ui-icon-triangle-1-n" : "ui-icon-triangle-1-s";
collection.find(".ui-icon").removeClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s").addClass("ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s");
$(this).find(".ui-icon").removeClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s").addClass(new_class);
```

as you can see it selects all header icon cells, removes any icon classes that may exist, then re-adds the applicable class. THEN i grab the clicked cells' icon, remove any icon classes, and apply the appropriate class.

Is this the best way to do this? It works.. and it executes in roughly 7 ms (Windows 7, FF6.0) which is ok by me.. just looks like it's a lot of work being done.

any thoughts?

Comment: 7 milliseconds? You're concerned about ***seven milliseconds?!*** How many elements are you dealing with? Any particular reason you're not using one of the many jQuery table plugins which already exist?

Comment: they did not fit my needs.. and when modifying them it proved to be more than enough work to justify building my own. also, it is not that 7ms is an issue for me. I just want to ensure this is in fact the best way to do this? can't forget about optimization even with the smallest tasks.

Comment: Is there a tool i can use to see jQuery operations in real time as page is loading and at the end see the total time each operation of individual scripts took?

Comment: This should probably be it's own question.. however.. as you have asked here: not that I know of, I just created a simple timer object for my testing. grab the current time. execute the script. grab a the current time (will be different), and compare the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have any other dynamic classes being assigned to these objects, then you can replace `o.removeClass().addClass()` with `o.attr("className", xxx)` since you know what the final result should be and you can speed it up by a factor of 3x (in my test case).

With your HTML and your code, I think it could be reduced to this:

```
var new_class = sort_info.order == "asc" ? "ui-icon-triangle-1-n" : "ui-icon-triangle-1-s";
collection.find(".ui-icon").attr("className", "ui-button-icon-secondary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s"); 
$(this).find(".ui-icon").attr("className", "ui-button-icon-secondary ui-icon " + new_class);
```

This should be faster because there's half as many jQuery calls and just setting an attribute is way faster than `addClass()` and `removeClass()`, but it is also more brittle and a bit less readable for what changes you're actually trying to make.  If you ever decide to add more classes to these objects, this code will have to be modified to account for them.  Only you can decide if this additional performance is worth a little reduction in maintainability.

You could reduce the number of selector operations by doing just one selector operation and then iterating over it with a custom function to decide whether each object is under this or not and assign it an appropriate className.  This both reduces the number of DOM searches, but also prevents duplicate assignment of className.  That would look something like this:

```
var new_class = sort_info.order == "asc" ? "ui-icon-triangle-1-n" : "ui-icon-triangle-1-s";
var that = this;
collection.find(".ui-icon").each(function() {
    if ($.contains(that, this)) {
        this.className = "ui-button-icon-secondary ui-icon " + new_class;
    } else {
        this.className = "ui-button-icon-secondary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s";
    }
});
```

Putting all three of these into a [jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/class-manipulation-performance) with only 10 items in the iteration, I get this in Chrome:

```
Your method: 6691 ops/sec
Direct set of className: 11,210 ops/sec
Iteration with single selector: 20,280 ops/sec
```

I get an even more dramatic difference in Firefox 6 (your method is even slower, my fast method is even faster).

So, it does appear things can be made to go a lot faster than what you have if that's relevant in your app.

Comment: Thanks! i'm about to leave work right now but I will test that out when I get home. I realize i'm being nitty gritty with small performance enhancements. However every ms counts..

Comment: Also, where Maintainability is concerned: I am designing this to tie directly into the JQuery Themes' css. So Once they are set they are set! this should be the only place in the code this is modified. If I want to programatically force a column to sort I will invoke a click event on it.

Comment: @rlemon - I added a jsperf test that shows my second method can be 3x faster than your method.

Comment: well my app is a data table as part of a web based CRM. so it will hold quite a few values (if the user so wishes) and I will be manipulating it a lot. so performance is a must! and if I can hone in the performance now and make it best practice I will be sure to implement these design practices in other aspects of the project.

Answer (score 1):

I think it won't matter much, but maybe this is faster (and you know how to measure it, so I'll let you be the judge):

```
var new_class = sort_info.order == "asc" ? "ui-icon-triangle-1-n" : "ui-icon-triangle-1-s";
collection.not(this).find(".ui-icon-triangle-1-n, .ui-icon-triangle-1-s").removeClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-icon-triangle-1-s").addClass("ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s");
$(this).find(".ui-icon").removeClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s").addClass(new_class);
```

But it won't matter that much afaik.

Comment: on average (1000 passes) your method increases performance by 1ms. :) cheers!

Comment: I updated the jsperf-test with this variant and another, difference seems to be bigger in those testcases :).